# Use unused mounted space

Tags: server, partitioning

I've currently got 3 HDDs and as a newbie I can't figure out for the sake of me how to use the unused space of the main HDD.

I've done the following:

```
sda             disk
|_sda1          part
  |_vg01-lv01   lvm    /data
sdb             disk
|_sdb1          part
  |_vg01-lv01   lvm    /data
```

And I am trying to merge the sdc3 remaining space to /data too but can't figure out how..

```
sdc                         disk
|_sdc1                      part
|_sdc2                      part   /boot
|_sdc3                      part
  |_ubuntu--vg-ubuntu-lvm   lvm    /
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with the following:

```
vgextend vg01 /dev/ubuntu-vg/sdc3
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vg01/lv01
resize2fs /dev/vg01/lv01
```

Hope that is the right way to do it!